# Wordpress Load More Post via button click

Tags: php, jquery, wordpress

I'm relatively new to Wordpress. So this might not be the best approach, or even possible. With that said, I'm open to better solution.

I have a homepage that will display the latest 12 posts.
I want to make a button that when clicked will load the next 4.

What I have currently is this:

```
<?php query_posts('showposts=4&offset=12'); ?>
<?php while (have_posts()): the_post(); ?>
    //some html tags
<?php endwhile; ?>
```

This will load me the detail of post 13-16.

I'm looking for a way where I can put this in a function and then call it through a jquery click() event where I can use a counter of some sort for the offset. something like

```
var offSetCounter = 12;

$(".btnLoadMore").click(function(){
    //php function call
    loadmore(offSetCounter);
    offSetCounter += 4;
});
```

So next time i click the button the offSetCounter would be 16 and so on.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: what does loadmore(offSetCounter) do?

Comment: hoping that would be a custom php function that will call the code in the first block

Comment: In your js/JQuery code you can only launch ajax request to php, but not php itself.

Answer (score 0):

To run on Wordpress try this:

PHP:

```
add_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_show_next_posts',  'show_next_posts' );
function show_next_posts() {
    $offset = $_POST['offset']; 
    $the_query = new  new WP_Query( array( 'posts_per_page' => 4, 'offset' => $offset ) );



    while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) {
        $the_query->the_post();
        echo '<div class="post_container">' . get_the_title() . '</div>';
    }
    wp_reset_postdata();
    wp_die();
    return;
}

add_action('wp_head','add_ajaxurl');
function add_ajaxurl() {
     $ajaxurl =  admin_url('admin-ajax.php');
     echo '<script type="text/javascript">
        var ajaxurl ='.$ajaxurl.';
     </script>';

}
```

JS:

```
jQuery('.btnLoadMore').click(function(){
    var offset = jQuery('.post_container').length();
    var data = {
        'action': 'show_next_posts',
        'offset': offset
    };

    jQuery.post(ajaxurl, data, function( response ) {
        console.log( response );
    });
});
```